# how to ssh to a server without password when there is no .ssh on it

Tags: ssh, passwords, public-key

I wanted to setup passwordless login from my local machine to this Linux server. When I tried to upload my public key I found that there is no .ssh on the server. So I created one with ssh-keygen on the server. However in the newly generated .ssh directory, there is no authorized_keys or known_hosts. So I made a new authorized_keys and pasted my public key from local machine. However it does not work, still need password for ssh. Can anyone tell me if I am doing it right?

Here is the output of ssh -vvv:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address .
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_198782' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_198782' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_198782' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /rsrch2/rists/djiao/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1477
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /rsrch2/rists/djiao/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /rsrch2/rists/djiao/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1573
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
```

Comment: you should check if the file and directory has correct permissions and if the server is even configured to check that path for authorized keys.

Comment: yes, I did that. .ssh is 755. authorized_keys is 600

Comment: `.ssh` should be 700, `authorized_keys` are ok.

Comment: if your server is using selinux, check the labels

Comment: @Jakuje can you be more specific? what is selinux and what labels?

Comment: `ls -Zd ~/.ssh` and `ls -Z ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should tell you

Comment: The output of the two commands are `drwx------  bdiuser infocust user_u:object_r:file_t      /inform/flatfiles/bdiuser/.ssh` and `-rw-------  bdiuser infocust user_u:object_r:file_t           /inform/flatfiles/bdiuser/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create it and copy your key over to it. If you have a key-copy tool then just create the file via

```
$ touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

before using the tool.

It might help to connect using -vvv for verbosity.

On the client and on the server, check that ~/.ssh has permissions 700.

On the server, check that `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Like I said, I manually created it and copied my key to it. I don't think the key-copy tool would make a difference, would it?

Comment: Then it is the permissions. It should be 700.

Comment: Another source of problems is on the client. Do you have 700 on ~/.ssh? 
`chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh`

If your key is not in the file id_rsa, you have to specify the filename in the ssh command when connecting, using the option `-i`.

Comment: .ssh on client was already 700. And I changed .ssh on the server to 700, still does not work.

Comment: What is the key file name?
Do you have
`PubkeyAuthentication yes`
and
`AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys` ?

Comment: standard filename, private key id_rsa, public key id_rsa.pub. It works for every other server just not this one. Should I do dsa instead?

Comment: What is the output when you connect using -vvv?

Comment: output added to the original post. Why does it try to look for id_dsa instead of id_rsa?

Comment: Please hide the IP addresses, though. It looks like it could be a server configuration. Is the server under your control? If so, check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for `PubkeyAuthentication` and `AuthorizedKeysFile`.

Comment: Looks like these two are commented out in sshd_config on the server. `#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
`  I don't have root for the server but if these two lines are uncommented, it should fix it, right?

Comment: Affirmative. I will update the answer then we can clean those comments.